# Can NetBeans debug PHP and JavaScript at same time?

Tags: debugging, netbeans

I want to debug JavaScript and PHP in NetBeans in same project. Is it possible?

Currently I am using an HTML5 project to debug JavaScript and a PHP project to debug PHP. I want professional method to debug both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible in upcoming NetBeans 7.4 (now available in Beta - link on netbeans.org or nightly builds from [here](http://bits.netbeans.org/netbeans/trunk/nightly/latest/))