# Debug Javascript in netbeans 7.4 inside PHP project

Tags: javascript, php, debugging, netbeans

I want to debug javascript code inside my php project in netbeans. I have read on several occasions that this should be possible in the new netbeans 7.4 version, for example [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/webclient/html5-js-support.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561107/can-netbeans-debug-php-and-javascript-at-same-time), but i cannot get it to work. I have installed de debugger connector for chrome and php debugging works just fine but when i try to set a breakpoint in a .js file it says:

> unresolved breakpoint,
>
> debugger is not attached to tab with id....

i understand that the link from the netbeans page is for an html 5 application but i thought this debugging would also be enabled in php projects. Am i doing something wrong?

i know i can debug with firebug or chrome itself but i would like to do it all in one place in my netbeans IDE...

thanks in advance

Comment: You can do this with firebug in Firefox or Google chromes inspector. Im not sure whether it can be done within Netbeans, but JS and PHP app/sites are usually on a web server and accessible through a browser

Comment: as i stated in my last part i understand this can be done from several browsers and plugins for these browsers such as firebug. I read however that this would also be possible within netbeans and i would like it if i can everything from within this IDE. Also i am developing the web system and have locak xampp config running as wel as a dedicated production environment so access is not a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unresolved breakpoint usually mean that for instance you set it in file that is not loaded in Chrome's tab right now (or for some reason, IDE cannot match URL of JS file and local JS file). The mixed debugging works only in Embdded Browser or in Chrome with NetBeans connector (you can see the usually yellow bar in your page saying "NetBeans connector is debugging this page" and you can debug PHP and JS at the same time.

Have a look [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeanswebclient/entry/html5_development_with_java_ee), although it is about Java EE projects, it is very similar to PHP projects

**Updated answer:**

One issue I remember (and plain Chrome Dev Tools has it as well) is that if you have JavaScript file attached to HTML/PHP with dynamic parameter to prevent browser from caching, e.g. , where "673612" changes each time a file is loaded. If that's your case, try to remove this dynamic attribute. I think that e.g. Sencha or ExtJS use this feature which "breaks" debuggers.

Comment: Thnx for the info and sorry for the late respone. I looked at your link and it basically states the same as elsewhere on the netbeans site.It should just work according to their info. I did install the netbeans connector and it shows the notice in chrome that netbeans is debugging the page. But it simply does not work, as soon as i set a breakpoint in my .js file it shows up as broken (not resolved/active at current line) and it does not stop on the line.

Comment: Also the embedded browser from netbeans has the same problem. I also tried to look at the sessions window and manually activate the javascript debugger session (is by default), but to no avail. I am thinking that it is somehow limited to java or html5 applications OR my x-debug session is somehow interfering (i set that up to debug my php)?

Comment: One issue I remember (and plain Chrome Dev Tools has it as well) is that if you have JavaScript file attached to HTML/PHP with dynamic parameter to prevent browser from caching, e.g. <script src=file.js?673612></script>, where "673612" changes each time a file is loaded. If that's your case, try to remove this dynamic attribute. I think that e.g. Sencha or ExtJS use this feature which "breaks" debuggers.

Comment: Thnx!! That did the trick, i was indeed using this dynamic parameter to prevent browser caching and once i disabled this it worked just fine! I tried loading a sample html 5 project and there the js debugging worked immediately so i thought that was the problem but now i know the issue, thnx very much!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem : javascript breakpoints were broken, while everything else was working fine (for example php breakpoints were okay).

The reason was that in the run configuration properties I changed the Project URL to something that was not the host anymore, but a subfolder managed by a url rewriting rule.

Answer (score 0):

johanvs is correct, but my reputation is not enough to +1.

Suppose a NetBeans project contains many files in different folders:

```
/var/www/index.html
/var/www/config.html
/usr/doc/readme.txt
/usr/doc/license.txt
```

Since "index.html" is not in the project root folder but under "/var/www", NetBeans does not know "http://127.0.0.1/index.html" is corresponding to "/var/www/index.html".  To solve, verify below settings in NetBeans -> File -> Project Properties:

1. Sources -> Web Root

   "var/www"
2. Run Configuration -> Project URL

   "http://127.0.0.1/"
3. Run Configuration -> Index File -> Browse

   "index.html"
4. Run Configuration -> Remote Connection -> Manage -> Initial Directory

   "/"
5. Run Configuration -> Upload Directory

   (empty)